# How to align div elements of innerDiv in one line

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var iCnt = 0;
```

creating div element

```
            var container = $(document.createElement('div')).css({
               ---some css--
            });
```

task showing status

```
            var status = { 0: "completed", 1: "completed", 2: "Running",                 3:"Pending", 4: "Pending" };
           var cssClass = '';

            iCnt = iCnt + 1;
            var i = 0;

            $.each(status, function (idx, i) { 

                                 }


                var innerDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).css({
                   -- some css---
                });

                $(container).append(innerDiv);
```

Now how to align these div elements of innerDiv one after the another in one line

```
            });

            $('#main').after(container);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: can you provide a illustration of your concept using
[senseful](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html)
[asciiflow](http://asciiflow.com/#Draw)

Comment: http://www.encodedna.com/2013/07/dynamically-add-remove-textbox-control-using-jquery.htm... as shown in dis ...bt i want the textboxes to b aligned in one line

Comment: trying adding float:left in css property for each div and provide enough width to outer div

Comment: Do not forget to up vote the answer, so that it helps other user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **This user's problem was solved by advice via comment**

***Try adding float:left in css property for each div and provide enough width to outer div***